# How can I return the influxdb query response to the Mainwindow class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in an asynchronous task a query to an influxdb database. I'm trying to return the result to a `MainWindow` class variable. Can someone help me?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        string result= ConsultaBD().Result;
  }


  public async Task<string>  ConsultaBD()
  {
        var influxDbClient = new InfluxDbClient("http://host:8086/", "user", "pass", InfluxDbVersion.v_1_3);
        var query = "SELECT T_PV FROM TFA WHERE time >= '2019-05-21' and time < '2019-05-22' ";
        var response = await influxDbClient.Client.QueryAsync(query, "dbName");

        return (response.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example await the `ConsultaBD()` method in an `async` event handler that gets invoked when the window has been loaded:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += async (s, e) =>
        {
            string result = await ConsultaBD();
        };
    }

    public async Task<string> ConsultaBD()
    {
        var influxDbClient = new InfluxDbClient("http://host:8086/", "user", "pass", InfluxDbVersion.v_1_3);
        var query = "SELECT T_PV FROM TFA WHERE time >= '2019-05-21' and time < '2019-05-22' ";
        var response = await influxDbClient.Client.QueryAsync(query, "dbName");

        return (response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Caling `Result` or `Wait()` on an `async` method is considered a bad practice and may deadlock.